# Pending state of deploying contract on Kovan network

Tags: go-ethereum, kovan

I am deploying my contract into Kovan network and faced with issue. When execute `truffle migrate` command it is go on blockchain and waits for confirmation:

`2018-01-11 18:36:55   TRACE own_tx  Signer: Awaiting confirmation... (1).`

Meanwhile in parity ui `parity signer` asks to unlock the account. After enter the password it goes into pending state. The assumption is it waits another block to use its hash for sign, though at this moment system in this pending state already 30 minutes.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tx was confirmed. It took an hour to do this.

Comment: Please either accept your own answer, or remove the original question. (Just to help keep the site clean.)

Comment: Thank you for reminder! In the past I noticed deleting answers were the reason to block my account, now I do my best don't do this. I need to wait some time before I can accept my own answer. For now it web site tells me it would be tomorrow.